# Advanced module for cross sell/accessoires

Tags: products, up-sells, cross-sells

I am looking for a module that can display cross sell/accessoires on the productpage.
But I am looking for a much more advanced solution than the default Magento method.

I want to display some products of a specific category, that is related to the product.

So that when someone buys a notebook, he/she can easily add a mouse, sleeve, software etc to the cart.

See this screenshot for example: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Does anyone knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your examples I would personally be inclined to evaluate Aheadworks Automatic Related Products - https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/automatic-related-products-2.html

The module will over time display common associations as related products as you seem to be looking for. You can also theme it as necessary in the usual way - copy the files into your theme and modify as necessary.

**Please note, I am not in any way affiliated to Aheadworks, I have simply used this module many times with good results.**